# Loop through xml elements and display in a table in a new row?

Tags: php, xml, domdocument

UPDATE:

How would I get this code to display in each row in a table. I have this table so far and I've tried putting this code before and inside the `<td>` but it won't put the above xml file onto a new line for each `<cogxml>`. Can you see where I am going wrong? Test 2.php is the php code that Parfait has in the answer.

```
<?php
   include_once('test2.php');
?>


    <html>

    <head>
        <title>CharGer and CoGui</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../XSLT/myStyle.css" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <div style="overflow-x:auto;">
            <?php
            include_once("../XSLT/upload4.php");
            ?>
            <div class="wrap">
              <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th width="5%">Concept Name</th>
                        <th width="5%">Relation Type</th>
                        <th width="44%">CoGui XML</th>
                        <th width="46%">CharGer XML</th>
                    </tr>
                        <tr>
                        <?php
                      for ($x=0; $x <=5; $x++){?>
                            <td>

                            </td>
                            <td>

                            </td>
                            <td>

<pre><code class="language-xml"><?php echo htmlspecialchars(file_get_contents($xmlfile), ENT_QUOTES); ?></code></pre>


                            </td>
                            <td>
                            </td>

                        </tr>
                        <?php 
                      }
                        ?>
                </table>
             </div>
     </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

This is what it looks like at the moment. It looks like this on each line but I only want each section of cogxml to appear in each row.
[image]

Comment: Classic example of a needed XSLT solution, the special-purpose language to transform XML documents. And like most general purpose langages, PHP comes equipped with an [XSLT processor](http://php.net/manual/en/class.xsltprocessor.php). Not one single `foreach` loop needed.

Comment: the title doesn't quite reflect the matching part. I'd say that the looping and the table part is the simpler task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned, consider an XSLT solution. Specifically, you will want an XSLT using the [Muenchian Grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html) on the `ctype/@id` value. PHP can process XSLT called externally in a separate file or embedded as a string. Below runs the former:

**XSLT** Script *(save as .xsl or .xslt to be used below in PHP)*

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="idkey" match="ctype" use="@id" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <root>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
    </root>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ctype[generate-id() = generate-id(key('idkey',@id)[1])]">
    <xsl:variable select="@id" name="id"/>
    <cogxml>
      <support>
        <xsl:attribute name="name"><xsl:value-of select="ancestor::support/@name"/></xsl:attribute>            
        <conceptTypes>                    
          <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>          
            <xsl:copy-of select="translation"/>
          </xsl:copy>
          <xsl:copy-of select="ancestor::conceptTypes/order[@id1=$id]"/>        
        </conceptTypes>      
        <relationTypes>
            <xsl:copy-of select="ancestor::support/relationTypes/rtype[contains(@idSignature, $id)]"/>
         </relationTypes>
      </support>
    </cogxml>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

**PHP** Script

```
// Load the XML source and XSLT file
$xml = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$xml->formatOutput = true;
$xml->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$xml->load('Input.xml');

$xsl = new DOMDocument;
$xsl->load('XSLTScript.xsl');

// Configure transformer
$proc = new XSLTProcessor;
$proc->importStyleSheet($xsl);

// Transform XML source
$newXML = new DOMDocument;
$newXML = $proc->transformToXML($xml);
echo $newXML;

// Save output to file
$xmlfile = 'Output.xml';
file_put_contents($xmlfile, $newXML);
```

**Transformed XML** *(separated by each cType)*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <cogxml>
    <support name="vocabulary">
      <conceptTypes>
        <ctype id="http://www.lirmm.fr/cogui#ct_043ea910-5f86-4150-b0f1-1418acf4db39" label="Junior Employee" x="250" y="10">
          <translation descr="" label="Junior Employee" lang="en"/>
        </ctype>
        <order id1="http://www.lirmm.fr/cogui#ct_043ea910-5f86-4150-b0f1-1418acf4db39" id2="http://www.lirmm.fr/cogui#ct_d7a78641-722f-4609-8f5a-90affc111e00"/>
      </conceptTypes>
      <relationTypes/>
    </support>
  </cogxml>
  <cogxml>
    <support name="vocabulary">
      <conceptTypes>
        <ctype id="http://www.lirmm.fr/cogui#ct_d7a78641-722f-4609-8f5a-90affc111e00" label="Employee" x="130" y="60">
          <translation descr="" label="Employee" lang="en"/>
        </ctype>
        <order id1="http://www.lirmm.fr/cogui#ct_d7a78641-722f-4609-8f5a-90affc111e00" id2="http://www.lirmm.fr/cogui#_ct_a12bacc5-bc88-429e-a7b1-45e143591288"/>
      </conceptTypes>
      <relationTypes/>
    </support>
  </cogxml>
  <cogxml>
    <support name="vocabulary">
      <conceptTypes>
        <ctype id="http://www.lirmm.fr/cogui#ct_feeca670-2f1c-433e-9271-4cffeda1e929" label="Director" x="250" y="110">
          <translation descr="" label="Director" lang="en"/>
        </ctype>
        <order id1="http://www.lirmm.fr/cogui#ct_feeca670-2f1c-433e-9271-4cffeda1e929" id2="http://www.lirmm.fr/cogui#ct_d7a78641-722f-4609-8f5a-90affc111e00"/>
      </conceptTypes>
      <relationTypes/>
    </support>
  </cogxml>
  <cogxml>
    <support name="vocabulary">
      <conceptTypes>
        <ctype id="http://www.lirmm.fr/cogui#ct_710bed80-a33e-4a13-b916-15fbb3357e8d" label="Manager" x="250" y="60">
          <translation descr="" label="Manager" lang="en"/>
        </ctype>
        <order id1="http://www.lirmm.fr/cogui#ct_710bed80-a33e-4a13-b916-15fbb3357e8d" id2="http://www.lirmm.fr/cogui#ct_d7a78641-722f-4609-8f5a-90affc111e00"/>
      </conceptTypes>
      <relationTypes/>
    </support>
  </cogxml>
  <cogxml>
    <support name="vocabulary">
      <conceptTypes>
        <ctype id="http://www.lirmm.fr/cogui#ct_cd84c648-ef22-4854-8e8c-a6654c0386be" label="Senior Employee" x="255" y="190">
          <translation descr="" label="Senior Employee" lang="en"/>
        </ctype>
        <order id1="http://www.lirmm.fr/cogui#ct_cd84c648-ef22-4854-8e8c-a6654c0386be" id2="http://www.lirmm.fr/cogui#ct_d7a78641-722f-4609-8f5a-90affc111e00"/>
      </conceptTypes>
      <relationTypes/>
    </support>
  </cogxml>
  <cogxml>
    <support name="vocabulary">
      <conceptTypes>
        <ctype id="http://www.lirmm.fr/cogui#_ct_a12bacc5-bc88-429e-a7b1-45e143591288" label="Top" x="10" y="60">
          <translation descr="" label="Top" lang="en"/>
        </ctype>
      </conceptTypes>
      <relationTypes>
        <rtype id="http://www.lirmm.fr/cogui#_rt_c42a5ce6-2f20-491d-8c91-501ae178a36c" idSignature="http://www.lirmm.fr/cogui#_ct_a12bacc5-bc88-429e-a7b1-45e143591288 http://www.lirmm.fr/cogui#_ct_a12bacc5-bc88-429e-a7b1-45e143591288" label="Link" x="10.0" y="10.0">
          <translation descr="" label="Link" lang="en"/>
        </rtype>
        <rtype id="http://www.lirmm.fr/cogui#rt_af40394c-9e62-4e92-b05b-352de5db876f" idSignature="http://www.lirmm.fr/cogui#_ct_a12bacc5-bc88-429e-a7b1-45e143591288 http://www.lirmm.fr/cogui#_ct_a12bacc5-bc88-429e-a7b1-45e143591288" label="senior" x="70.0" y="10.0">
          <translation descr="" label="senior" lang="en"/>
        </rtype>
      </relationTypes>
    </support>
  </cogxml>
</root>
```

---

To render HTML table, you can extend the XSLT script above and keep exact PHP script but just save output as HTML: 'Output.html'. Recall XSLT transforms XML into multiple formats: XML, HTML, even text. Here `<cogxml>` will render in each row of table.

**HTML** Table:

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="idkey" match="ctype" use="@id" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
     <html>

      <head>
        <title>CharGer and CoGui</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../XSLT/myStyle.css" />
      </head>

      <body>
        <div style="overflow-x:auto;">
          <div class="wrap">
              <table>
                    <tr>
                      <th width="5%">Concept Name</th>
                      <th width="5%">Relation Type</th>
                      <th width="44%">CoGui XML</th>
                      <th width="46%">CharGer XML</th>
                    </tr>
                      <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
              </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </body>
     </html>

  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ctype[generate-id() = generate-id(key('idkey',@id)[1])]">
    <xsl:variable select="@id" name="id"/>
      <tr>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
          <pre>

          <cogxml>
            <support>
              <xsl:attribute name="name"><xsl:value-of select="ancestor::support/@name"/></xsl:attribute>            
              <conceptTypes>                    
                <xsl:copy>
                  <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>          
                  <xsl:copy-of select="translation"/>
                </xsl:copy>
                <xsl:copy-of select="ancestor::conceptTypes/order[@id1=$id]"/>        
              </conceptTypes>      
              <relationTypes>
                  <xsl:copy-of select="ancestor::support/relationTypes/rtype[contains(@idSignature, $id)]"/>
               </relationTypes>
            </support>
          </cogxml>


          </pre>
        </td>
      </tr> 
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

Comment: Thankyou for this. This works perfectly. It is exactly how I wanted it to be  but I couldn't get it to work using a foreach and if statements.

Comment: See my edit where I extend the XSLT script to render an HTML output. Additionally you can run xslt as a stylesheet on original XML document using the declaration [<xml:stylesheet>](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_transformation.asp). Here the browser runs XSLT not PHP.

Comment: Thanks why do I need to save it as html? Shouldn't it be xml? So won't this work with php?

Comment: Either XML or HTML will work and with PHP. I just show that XSLT can transform to either formats. A well-formed HTML is an XML document! The only challenge is viewing the XML content between `<pre>` tags in browser (currently only in markup), but PHP can replace such content with `htmlspecialchars()`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of deleting the non-matches, **build a new file for each `<ctype>`.**

To accomplish this,
 1. iterate over all `<ctype>` nodes
 1. get the `id`-attribute and select all `<order>` and `<rtype>` nodes that match
 2. copy the results to a new DOM.

#### Iterate over all `<ctype>` nodes, get the id:

```
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName("ctype") as $ctype) {
    $id = $ctype->getAttribute('id');
    // more code will go here...
}
```

#### select the matches, using `xpath`

Set up the `xpath`-expressions:

```
/cogxml/support/conceptTypes/order[@id1='$id']
```

Note the condition is in `[]`, the `@` signals `attribute`. In this case, `id1`-attribute of the `<order>` node has to match `$id`:

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$orders = $xpath->query("/cogxml/support/conceptTypes/order[@id1='$id']");
```

Result is a `DOMNodeList` as `$orders`, there might be `0` or more matches.
Same procedure matching the `id`-attribute of the `<rtype>`-nodes.

#### build a new DOM and copy the nodes from the source to it

```
$newdom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
$newdom->loadXML("<cogxml><support><conceptTypes /><relationTypes /></support></cogxml>");
```

This is setting up the basic XML corpus. Now add the `<ctype>` and its matching nodes we selected - `importNode()` will do the job. Note that we need the parent `<conceptTypes>` in the new DOM to call `appendChild`:

```
$newnode = $newdom->importNode($ctype, true);
$newdom->getElementsByTagName("conceptTypes")->item(0)->appendChild($newnode);
```

There might be multiple matching orders, so we iterate:

```
foreach ($orders as $order) {
    $newnode = $newdom->importNode($order, true);
    $newdom->getElementsByTagName("conceptTypes")->item(0)->appendChild($newnode);
}
```

Copying `$rtypes` is following the same procedure.
Finally, save the new DOM to XML:

```
$newdom->saveXML("mynewfile.xml");
```

Putting it all together and streamlining:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
$dom->loadXML($x); // assume source XML in $x

$newdom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName("ctype") as $ctype) {

    $newdom->loadXML("<cogxml><support><conceptTypes /><relationTypes /></support></cogxml>");

    $newnode = $newdom->importNode($ctype, true);
    $newdom->getElementsByTagName("conceptTypes")->item(0)->appendChild($newnode);

    $id = $ctype->getAttribute('id');

    foreach ($xpath->query("/cogxml/support/conceptTypes/order[@id1='$id']") as $order) {
        $newnode = $newdom->importNode($order, true);
        $newdom->getElementsByTagName("conceptTypes")->item(0)->appendChild($newnode);
    }    

    foreach ($xpath->query("/cogxml/support/relationTypes/rtype[@id='$id']") as $rtype) {
        $newnode = $newdom->importNode($rtype, true);
        $newdom->getElementsByTagName("relationTypes")->item(0)->appendChild($newnode);
    }    

    echo $newdom->saveXML(); // echo to screen 
}
```

see it in action: https://eval.in/527124

Comment: Thank you for this it works perfectly but I decided to go with the other answer.